# Updating product stock based on shopping cart quantity and updating cart items when product is changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, e-commerce

just a (hopefully) quick one today, apologies if it's super simple and I'm just thick.

I'm have a basic e-commerce app that I'm working on, and have 2 questions:

1. I'd create a :product in admin with an amount of stock. I'm looking to automatically update the stock of a :product if one or more is added to someone's cart as a :cart_item, based on the quantity that they've got in their cart (even before checkout). So one update if a product is added, and another update if a customer changes quantity from the cart view.
2. I'd like the name and price of :cart_item in a customers cart to be updated automatically if admin updates the associated :product.

Here are my model associations so far:

```
Customer
  has_one :cart
  has_many :orders

Product
  has_many :cart_items

Cart
  belongs_to:customer
  has_many :cart_items

CartItem
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :cart
```

I only have scaffolds so far so all my current code is out of the box Rails 3.2.14.

I'm just not sure how to get the :cart_items to interact with the :products and vice versa. What code/extra functionality should I add to get this working? Thanks for the help.

Comment: just a suggestion but keep in mind most shopping carts are abandoned. normally stock would not be adjusted until after the transaction has gone through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `CartItem` `belongs_to :product` (which seems likely), and has a `quantity` attribute that indicates the number in the cart:

1) I believe the functionality you want could be accomplished using callbacks on `CartItem`. For instance,

```
class CartItem < AR:B
  after_save :remove_from_stock
  after_destroy :return_to_stock


  def remove_from_stock
    product.stock -= self.quantity
    product.save
  end

  def return_to_stock
    product.stock += self.quantity
    product.save
  end
end
```

2) When you display the `CartItem`, just refer to it's associated product:

```
<% @cart_items.each do |cart_item| %>
  Item Name: <%= cart_item.product.name %>
  Item Price: <%= cart_item.product.price %>
<% end %>
```

This way, any change to the associated `Product` will be reflected in any view that refers to it.
If you're displaying many at once, make sure to use eager loading to avoid N+1 queries:

```
@cart_items = CartItem.includes(:product).where(<whatever>)
```